# Avoid direct access to static content in webapps

Tags: java, html, spring, servlets, shiro

I have integrated my Spring MVC application Shiro for security reasons.

All my urls are working fine, but I have a few html pages which can be directly accessed.

How can I protect those pages, meaning if a user is not logged in to an application, and tries to open an html page, they should be redirected to the login page.

I have tested on jetty and tomcat server.

**Jetty**

```
http://ip:port - works fine, redirects to login page

http://ip:port/html/ - opens html pages
```

**Tomcat**

```
http://localhost:8070/my-app/html/myPage.html - opens html pages
```

Basically I do not want direct access of my static content without a user being logged in.

My html file is integrated with angular code. Is there any sort of servlet that can create and return html from it. Meaning I will read html from some other specific location, parse and return html in response.

**html file location** - `my-app\html\myPage.html`

**Shiro settings in `web.xml`**

```
filter>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

When i build war, it copies images, html folder outside web-inf also.
**How can avoid copying images, html folder outside web-inf using maven**

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid direct access to page by placing them inside the WEB-INF folder.

Comment: when i create war file, it places my html folder inside web-inf and also outside it, how can i avoid that

Answer (score 0):

in shiro ini try

```
[url]

/*.html = authc
```

Following you can use but still recommended is to use from shiro.ini as you never know when your application grows and it would be unmanageable to do this from web.xml. It also makes web.xml fat this is for non spring. The configuration you are showing are only for shiro setup not for securing urls. For securing urls either you have to make them programmatically or from web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param><param-name>config</param-name><param-value>

    # INI Config Here

    [url]

    /*.html = authc



    </param-value></init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: i have added my shiro url pattern from web.xml